# Preserving Data Groupings when writing to Worksheet using OpenPyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

**Disclaimer:** I am a beginner-level, self-taught casual 'programmer' with Python.

**Background:** I have a script that takes Groupings of data from an `.xlsx` Workbook and writes them to separate Worksheets of a seperate `.xlsx` like so -

**Before state** (`original_data.xlsx`): you will note each top-level is a Client, underneath sits multiple levels of underyling data, pertaining to it's parent client.
[image]

**After state** (`split_data.xlsx`): you will note each client and their underlying data is written to an identically named Worksheet in a new `.xlsx` file like so:
[image]

**Issue:** you will note from the `After state` that the Groupings / Levels have been lost, whilst all the data is present and has different levels of indentation.

Does anyone know how I might enhance my script to ensure that the Groupings / Levels are preserved? E.g., so you can still expand each Grouping (e.g., Client A) like so:
[image]

**My script:** here is the script (sorry it's messy!) which achieves the above, minus the preserved Grouping/Levels.

```
import openpyxl

from copy import copy
from openpyxl import load_workbook

columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L']
def copy_cell(ws, row,ws_row,ws1):
    for col in columns:
        ws_cell=ws1[col+str(ws_row)]
        new_cell = ws[col+str(row)]

        if ws_cell.has_style:
            new_cell.font = copy(ws_cell.font)
            new_cell.border = copy(ws_cell.border)
            new_cell.fill = copy(ws_cell.fill)
            new_cell.number_format = copy(ws_cell.number_format)
            new_cell.protection = copy(ws_cell.protection)
            new_cell.alignment = copy(ws_cell.alignment)

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('original_data.xlsx')

ws1=wb1.active

indexs=[]
clients=[]

index=1

while ws1['A'+str(index)]:
    if str(ws1['A'+str(index)].alignment.indent)=='0.0':
        indexs.append(index)
        clients.append(ws1['A'+str(index)].value)
    if ws1['A'+str(index)].value  is None:
        indexs.append(index)
        break
    index+=1

wb1.close()

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

ws=wb.active

start_index=1

headers=['Ownership Structure', 'Fee Schedule', 'Management Style', 'Advisory Firm', 'Inception Date', 'Days in Time Period', 'Adjusted Average Daily Balance (No Div, USD)', 'Assets Billed On (USD)',
'Effective Billing Rate', 'Billing Fees (USD)', 'Bill To Account', 'Model Type']

for y,index in enumerate(indexs):
    try:
        client=0
        if len(clients[y])>=32:
            client=clients[y][:31]
        else:
            client=clients[y]
        wb.create_sheet(client)
        ws=wb[client]
        ws.column_dimensions['A'].width=35
        ws.append(headers)
        row_index=2
        for i in range(start_index,indexs[y+1]):
            ws.append([ws1[col+str(i)].value for col in columns])
            copy_cell(ws,row_index,i,ws1)
            row_index+=1
        start_index=indexs[y+1]
    except:
        pass

wb.save('split_data.xlsx')
wb.close()

try:
    wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('split_data.xlsx')
    a=wb1['Sheet']
    wb1.remove(a)
    a=wb1['Sheet1']
    wb1.remove(a)
    wb1.save('split_data.xlsx')
    wb1.close()
except:
    pass
```

**Resources:** [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ZDsS070izZ4GvqDjil4OW_NLEAe4gEj/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111177902366405108541&rtpof=true&sd=true) is a link to some test data (`original_data.xlsx`)

Comment: Unable to download your test sheet (download is corrupt every time). Would probably expect the grouping to be lost however openpyxl can create grouping using row_dimension and column_dimension e.g. **sheet.row_dimensions.group(rowA,rowB, outline_level=1)** so you should be able to re-add the missing groups to the new sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def get_client_rows(sheet):
    """Get client rows.

    Skip header and then look for row dimensions without outline level
    """
    return [row[0].row for row in sheet.iter_rows(2) if row[0].alignment.indent == 0.0]
    return [
        row_index
        for row_index, row_dimension in sheet.row_dimensions.items()
        if row_index > 1 and row_dimension.outline_level == 0
    ]


def delete_client_block(sheet, start, end):
    """
    Delete rows starting from up to and including end.
    """
    for row in range(start, end + 1):
        sheet.row_dimensions.pop(row, None)
    sheet.delete_rows(start, end - start + 1)


def split_workbook(input_file, output_file):
    """
    Split workbook each main group into its own sheet.

    Not too loose any formatting we copy the current sheet and remove all rows
    which do not belong to extacted group.
    """

    try:
        workbook = load_workbook(input_file)
        data_sheet = workbook.active
        client_rows = get_client_rows(data_sheet)

        for index, client_row in enumerate(client_rows):
            # create new sheet for given client, shorten client as it might be too long
            client_sheet = workbook.copy_worksheet(data_sheet)
            client_sheet.title = data_sheet.cell(client_row, 1).value[:32]

            # delete rows after current client if available
            if index < len(client_rows) - 1:
                row_after_client = client_rows[index + 1]
                delete_client_block(
                    client_sheet, row_after_client, client_sheet.max_row
                )

            # delete rows before current client if available
            if index > 0:
                first_client_row = client_rows[0]
                delete_client_block(
                    client_sheet, first_client_row, client_row - first_client_row + 1
                )

                # move left over dimensions to top of the sheet
                for row_index in list(client_sheet.row_dimensions.keys()):
                    # skip header row dimension
                    if row_index > first_client_row - 1:
                        row_dimension = client_sheet.row_dimensions.pop(row_index)
                        new_index = row_index - client_row + first_client_row
                        row_dimension.index = new_index
                        client_sheet.row_dimensions[new_index] = row_dimension

        del workbook[data_sheet.title]
        workbook.save(output_file)
    finally:
        workbook.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file = 'data.xlsx'
    output_file = "data_output.xlsx"

    split_workbook(input_file, output_file)
```